# JScrollPane does not immediately refresh scrollbars

Tags: java, swing, zooming, bufferedimage, jscrollbar

Basically, I am new to Java and my guess is that the issue I'm having has a lot to do with the way Java's UI framework is implemented.

Here's the catch:
I have Implemented a control that allows zooming in and out of a displayed BufferedImage

I have an image rendered on a JPanel, the JPanel is contained within a scrollbar.

Zooming in\out etc works perfectly.

The Scrollbars are rendered correctly on Zoom In and disappear when I zoom out.

I want to add the functionality of focusing on a specific quarter of the displayed image

via four dedicated buttons, each send an int (1-4) to this method, that controls the scrollbars.

```
public void zoomToQuarter(int i) 
{
    double width = (currentBufferedImage.getWidth()*2.2)+1;
    double height = (currentBufferedImage.getHeight()*2.2)+1;

    JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    JScrollBar horizontal = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();

    horizontal.setMaximum((int)width);
    vertical.setMaximum((int)height);

    //scrollPane.revalidate();  

    BufferedImage zoomedImage = ImageUtilities.resizeImage(currentBufferedImage, width, height);
    renderBefferedImage(zoomedImage);
    focusedOnSubLocation = true;

    switch (i)
    {   
        case(1):
            vertical.setValue(0);
            horizontal.setValue(0);
            break;
        case(2):
            vertical.setValue(0);
            horizontal.setValue(horizontal.getMaximum());
            break;
        case(3):
            vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
            horizontal.setValue(0);
            break;
        case(4):
            vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
            horizontal.setValue(horizontal.getMaximum());
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }        
}
```

A click on one of the four buttons immediately propagates to this method

```
q1Button = new JButton("Q1");
                lowerZoomPanel.add(q1Button);
                q1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        sgiImagePanel.pause();
                        sgiImagePanel.zoomToQuarter(1);
                        sgiImagePanel.revalidate();
                        sgiImagePanel.repaint();
                    }
                });
```

And resizes the image whilst scrolling the scrollbars accordingly,

The method works as expected, but only once I click a button ( any of the four) twice.

From that moment on, each click to any button correctly scrolls the scrollbars etc.

Why?

Comment: Don't change the size of the scroll bars so much as change the size of the view, via the `getPreferredSize` method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I am not changing the scrollbar size, I am changing it's position. the zooming works fine.. the issue is with the programatic scrolling.

Comment: @MadProgrammer note the above comment

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/634143/GUI/java/JScrollbar-JScrollpane-programatical-scrolling

Comment: @EyalPerry What notes?  The size of the scroll bars should be calculated by the scroll pane based on you components preferred size and the viewable area of the scroll pane...?

Comment: You are basically re-implementing the functionality of `scrollRectToVisible(...)`. Why not use that method directly? :-)